# Unable to push to github private repo

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to push to a private repo on Github but I'm unable to either push or pull from this repo.

Please note I have a 2-factor authentication setup for this Github account. Do I need to perform or configure anything to get connected to the private repository?

Although when I ping I'm getting a proper response. It is only failing while pushing or pulling from the repo.

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/xyz/abc.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Operation timed out
```

I'm Microsoft Visual Studio Code as my editor.

Thank you so much for your help in advance.

Comment: It seems like you are behind a proxy/firewall or not connected to internet, just check it once

Comment: No I'm on the home network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using iTerm and when I switched to the default Mac OS terminal it worked fine. Very strange. Thank you so much everyone for your kind help. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are getting a connection timeout, the most likely cause of this issue is to be found in something network related and not related to git/github.
I would suggest you first try to connect to this git repository with a browser on the same machine as where you are using Visual Studio. If that works, you know that the machine is able to access github. If this doesn't work, I suggest you look at any firewall/router you need to pass to reach github and check if the connection is allowed and being routed in the correct way.

Comment: I'm on the home network, I can access my repo through web (github.com) completely fine without any issue.

Answer (score -1):

Github 2-Way Authentication requires a user access token instead of the user password while running pull and push operation in GITHUB.

```
Without 2FA
    $ git clone https://github.com/ashish-webkul/webkul-repo.git
        Username: your_username
        Password: your_password
With 2FA
    $ git clone https://github.com/ashish-webkul/webkul-repo.git
        Username: your_username
        Password: your_access_token
```

1. Then first we need to know how to set up access token key on GITHUB account for the command line. Steps are given below,
2. First of all, make sure your email-id should be verified. If not then verify first.

   Then go to the top right corner of your GITHUB account. Where you will see your profile picture. Click on that picture and then click on setting.

[image: 1]

GITHUB Main Settings

3. Then on the left side menubar, you will see “Developer Setting“. Click on it and then click on “Personal access tokens”

[image: 2]

Developer Setting

4. Then you will see a button “Generate new token“. Click on that button to generate an access token,

[image: 3]

Token Menu

5. then after giving the access token name select the permission which you would like to give for that token.

[image: 4]

GITHUB Token Name

[image: 5]

Select permissions for access tokens

5. After that click on “Generate Token“. Then you token will appear on the window.

[image: 6]

GITHUB Account Token

This is how you can create an access token.

NOTE: Keep your access token secret

Now you can use an access token as your authentication password for GITHUB pull & push operations.